# HW with exception (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class TestMorseCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Morse Code Conversion Program.");
    System.out
            .println("This program reads a phrase in English(or Morse code) and prints its equivalent in Morse code (or English).");
    for (;;) {
        int choice = 0;
        System.out.println();
        System.out
                .println("Please select one [1-3]: \n1: English -> Morse \n2: Morse -> English \n3: Quit");
        try {
            choice = input.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            System.out.println("-------- EXCEPTION --------");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            input.nextLine();
            continue;
        }
        input.nextLine();
        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter an English phrase:");
            String phrase = input.nextLine();
            int j = phrase.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                try {
                    System.out
                            .print(MorseCode.toMorseCode(phrase.charAt(i)));
                } catch (AlphabetException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            System.out.println("Enter a Morse phrase:");
            String phrase = input.nextLine();
            String[] words = phrase.split("\\s+");
            int w = words.length;
            System.out.println(w);
            char[][] code = new char[w][];
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++) {
                    code[i][j] = words[i].charAt(j);
                }

                for (int k = 0; i < code[k].length; k++) {
                    try {
                        System.out.print(MorseCode.fromMorseCode(code[k]));
                    } catch (AlphabetException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

I am having a problem with the toMorseCode method I keep receiving the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestMorseCode.main(TestMorseCode.java:50)
```

line 50 corresponds to:

```
 code[i][j] = words[i].charAt(j);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've initialized the 2nd dimension of your code array, and so it appears at risk of being null. But more importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: oh i see now, thank you, but also since the char[][] can vary in length how would i then define it?

Comment: You need to either use an ArrayList, or define that dimension **when you know what its length should be**, and definitely **before using it**.

Comment: So perhaps in the for loop after `for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {` before the inner for loop where you use the 2nd dimension (a guess as I haven't really studied your code).

Answer (score 0):

You never initialze the 2nd dimineion of your code array, and so it remains null, since all arrays must be initialized before you start to fill them. So do that:

```
char[][] code = new char[w][];
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {

    //   **** here ****
    code[i][] = new char[words[i].length()]; // *****

    for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++) {
        code[i][j] = words[i].charAt(j);
    }
```